# help with google android

Tags: java, android

how powerfull is google android bluetooth programming?

is it considered a low level programming langauge/emulator that enables me to have full control over bluetooth? ie protocols,encryption,layers....

Comment: Your title sucks man! `It should be Question on Google android bluetooth programming` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go through the Android Reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html . It will give u the complete idea of the bluetooth APIs.

Dev Guide also has fair amount of information over it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html